# Should you shade your dependencies?

Tags: java, apache-spark, gradle, dependencies

For my job I use `Spark` every day.  One of the problems comes from dependency conflicts.  I can't help but think that they would all go away if people released their jars already shaded to their own namespace.

For internal jars, I'm considering doing this for all our dependencies.  Other than a small bit of work, I'm seeing this as a good idea.  Is there any drawbacks/risks I'm missing?

Comment: There's obviously an issue with bloat. If you include 10 libraries each with their own version of `Spark` then the `Spark` jars will be 10 times as large as if you used dependency resolution to pick a single version. If you publish all versions to a repository (eg nexus) then you may find the extra jars start to take up a fair bit of disk space on nexus

Comment: this question is a pit, and at the bottom is a realization - whatever suits you is best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems go away with shading, but new problems arise. One problem is that you take away the chance for your users to use a different (patched) version of a dependency than the version used in shading.
But the main risk of shading is that shaded classes end up exposed to clients.

So imagine you have 2 dependencies a, b, each shading log4j. So when you include a and b, you get classes a.shaded.log4j.Logger(v1.3) and b.shaded.log4j.Logger(1.4) on your compile/runtime classpath. And you may have your own log4j.Logger(1.5).

Then you want to do something with all Loggers in your system at runtime, but suddenly you get many different logger classes and class version at runtime.

So shading is only without risk when you can make sure that the clients will not ever see any instances of shaded classes via the API of your library. But this is very difficult to guarantee. Maybe with modules in Java9 this will be a little less problematic, but even then having just one known version of any class on the classpath is much easier to debug/manage than a wild mix of shaded classes with same names but different versions.